# why isn't hadoop distributing a file to all nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I set up a 4 node hadoop cluster according to the walk-through in http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/. I used replication of 1 (the cluster is just for testing)

I copied a 2GB file from local. When browsing the file in the http interface I see it was split to 31 blocks, but all of them are on one node (the master)

Is this correct? How can I investigate the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all on one node because by default Hadoop will write to the local node first by default. I'm going to guess you were using the Hadoop client from that node. Since you have a replication of one, it's only going to be on that node.

Since you are just playing around, you might want to force spreading the data out. To do this, you can run the [rebalancer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#balancer) with `hadoop rebalancer`. Just control-C it after a few minutes.

Comment: hadoop balancer gives me 'The cluster is balanced. Exiting...'